# Favicon for Amazon s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, favicon

Hey I've a bucket in s3 which have pdf files. These files open in as default browser pdf viewer. Is it possible to add default favicon to the bucket. So, for each file this favicon appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible if you add a favicon.ico to the root of the bucket and make the object publically accessible. By default browsers will look for the sitewide favicon if opening the PDF in an iframe.